# multiple events avoid multiple calls

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox and I am using the keyup event for live() *- people writing new code should use on() -* but the problem was people could copy and paste values in, drag values in or use the autocomplete to change the values.

To resolve the problem, I am finding that I can use the following:

```
$(".textbox").live("keyup change input", function(){
```

This works but the problem is obviously that the function is called multiple times in certain cases and in certain browsers. I can't seem to think of a way to avoid this problem.  Does anyone have any quick ideas? It isn't the end of the world if the code is called multiple times as it's just updating some values on the page, but it would be nice to learn how to fix this problem! Thanks!

*EDIT: I forgot to mention it before but I am using jQuery 1.4.4 and on() is not usuable.*

Comment: $("body").on("keyup change input", '.textbox', function(e){
if(e.type == 'keyup')
....

Comment: @Kirix and if the user copy and pasted text into the box by right-clicking? What happens?

Comment: oh, sorryt... It was a late time... I thought that `keyup change input` are 3 events, like `focusing focusout`

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion and Correction**

The function `$.live()` is deprecated. So change the following code:

```
$(".textbox").live("keyup change input", function(){
```

To:

```
$("body").unbind("keyup").unbind("change").unbind("input").on("keyup change input", ".textbox", function(){
```

This resolves multiple attachment of events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Quick question though: Won't calling $("body").unbind("click") remove all click events?

Comment: @James Yeah, it does. Then it will add only the ... Oops... Taht should have been `.unbind("keyup").unbind("change").unbind("input")`. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: There are hundreds of other events on the page though, I can't remove all of these events.

Comment: Okay, just omit the `.unbind()`s.

Comment: But then won't we just return to the same situation? When a user presses a key in chrome the function will be called multiple times?

Comment: Nopes... This is the improvement from `.live()` to `.on()`. Try this and let me know. I am wating... :)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake and forgot to mention my jquery version.  I cannot use on() because I am using jquery 1.4.4.

Comment: @James Can you upgrade your jQuery? It is very very old. Is there any reason for having such an old one?

Answer (score 0):

If multiple events happen but the value is not changed then we can ignore those events. So, you can maintain the old value and compare with the new value to decide whether should do something or not:

```
$(".textbox").live("keyup change input", function(e){
    if($(this).attr("old-value") !== $(this).val()){
        // do something

        // update old-value
        $(this).attr("old-value", $(this).val());
    }
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/NYmYJ/3/